# Deactivate/Activate a users post on Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I have two post nodes in Firebase, **public_posts** and **user_posts**. Instead of deleting a post permanently, I would like users to deactivate their post. So that in the future if the user wants to activate the post back they can.

**user_posts** node would contain posts that are created by authenticated users. So the view controller that shows the authenticated users post can show if the post is activated or deactivated in a simple label.

**public_posts** contains posts that are visible to public. However, I would not like the public view controller to show deactivated user posts.

```
"public_posts" : {
  "Home" : {
    "Single Room" : {
      "-Kx-oQs5MEmnC5wTdXBr" : {
        "description" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum",
        "location" : "United States",
        "title" : "Room for rent"
      }
    }
  }
},
"user_posts" : {
  <$uid> : {
    "-Kx-oQs5MEmnC5wTdXBr" : {
      "category" : "Home",
      "description" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum",
      "location" : "United States",
      "subCategory" : "Single Room",
      "title" : "Room for rent"
    }
  }
}
```

How would I go about implementing this logic?
Currently, this is how I am reading posts for both **user_posts** and **public_posts**.

```
guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
let ref = Database.database().reference()        
ref.child("user_posts").child(userId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

          if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                  value["title"] as? String
                  //etc...
                }

        }, withCancel: nil )
```